# xml kafka message to dataframe using pyspark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have an xml message from a kafka topic and im looking to convert the incoming  message to a dataframe and use it further. I have achieved the same for json messages but not with xml. if anyone could help on the same.

code with json(working alright):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType()),
    StructField("value", StringType())
])

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "topic-name") \
    .load() \
    .select(from_json(df.value.cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value"))
```

I tried to use xml parse from xmltodict module to create a udf and apply it on the field of the data frame. It works as expected.

```
import xmltodict
import json
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

def xml_to_json_udf(xml_string):
    xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_string)
    json_data = json.dumps(xml_dict)
    return json_data 

xml_to_json_udf = sf.udf(parse_xml, StringType())
```

Later used in the dataframe like this :

```
df = df.withColumn('xml_column_as_xml', xml_to_json_udf(df._kafka_value))  # _kafka_value in string datatype
```

However one error that i face is when the message comes from a kafka producer the string value doesnt get parsed as an xml(still trying to figure it out).

Comment: Try using spark-xml library... Otherwise, you need to write your own UDF where you can use xml2dict

Comment: I created an udf as you had mentioned to parse the xml before making it a json. but somehow the incoming kafka message is adding a '\' before the equals sign and due to that the xml parser is not working. if i pass it without that the xml to json works properly. i tried all sorts to escape or remove the backslash but it always fails with the "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token) "  my code is like below:  def xml_to_json_udf(xml_string):
     xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_string)
     json_data = json.dumps(xml_dict)
     return json_data

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your new issue/code. You'll need to look at your kafka producer code to know why strings would be escaped

Comment: I tried it using my edited code, but still facing an issue with the expat error due to some random string causing the malformed xml issue

Comment: Well, you can use try-except within your udf to `return None` or empty string, when parsing fails, then you can filter that out later

Comment: So finally, this is what i did and was able to resolve my issue. The kafka message had text containing('/n','/t' and '/"') which was not letting the xmltodict to convert them to a json. i used python string (xml_string1.replace('\\"', '"').replace('\\n','').replace('\\t','').replace('\\r','')) after which i was able to resolve the expat issue. Thanks @OneCricketeer for your valuable guidance on this

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as a complete answer below

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used the below code to get this done. May be it will help someone in the future.
this is what i did and was able to resolve my issue. The kafka message had text containing('/n','/t' and '/"') which was not letting the xmltodict to convert them to a json. i used python string (xml_string1.replace('\"', '"').replace('\n','').replace('\t','').replace('\r','')) after which i was able to resolve the expat issue

```
import xmltodict
import json
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

#xml_string is the data coming from the dataframe
def parse_xml(xml_string):
    #creating a functional string with the incoming data
    xml_string1=f"{xml_string}"
    #Trim the string
    xml_string1=xml_string1.strip()
    #check if my input string starts and ends with double qoutes and remove them
    if xml_string1.startswith('\"') and xml_string1.endswith('\"'):
        xml_string1 = xml_string1[1:-1]
    #replace the unwanted characters
    xml_string1 = xml_string1.replace('\\"', '"').replace('\\n','').replace('\\t','').replace('\\r','')
    xml_string1=f"{xml_string1}"
    #parse the new string 
    xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_string1)
    #convert to json
    json_data = json.dumps(xml_dict)
    #print(json_data,"jsondata")
    return json_data
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).